# Delay on Modal pop up in master page - web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, modalpopupextender

My modal pops up with a delay and its weird. In debug mode, the line `ModalPopupExtender2.Show();` is already executed.

**Master.Master.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
}
```

**Master.Master**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:Label ID="lbldummy" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

<act:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalpop" TargetControlID="lbldummy" PopupControlID="button">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-scrollable" id="button" runat="server">
 // some content
</div>

</form>
```

Why my modal pop up slowly? I think within 2-3 seconds.

For troubleshooting, I already tried to show ModalPopupExtender using javascript and it works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably because ModalPopupExtender is slow, and Web Forms is slow, and you have to be careful not to do things that make it slow. Instead of relying on these leaky abstractions, why not take the time to learn how to do client side development? Pick a library and use it to create nice looking popups without the need for server interaction. Something like [Boostrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: You're right. Its better to pick a client side development for modals. ModalPopupExtender works normally in WebForms not in master page, in other word, when i put my ModalPopupExtender  in master this problem occurs, and I noticed in debug mode that I always returns in master page within 2-3 seconds then the modal pop up.

Comment: And for troubleshooting, I already tried to show ModalPopupExtender using javascript and it works fine without delay.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ASP.NET - Life Cycle](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_life_cycle.htm), Page Load is called quite soon. Before the rest of the server function calls are completed and then your browser finishes rendering html on the client, popup is not shown. 
That's I guess is the source of the delay until you provide what's happening on the rest of the code.

Comment: Maybe you're right, i dont know why in other web forms except master page. This modal pop up works fine without delay. Note that the modalshow is on Page load also. Hope you get what i mean.

Comment: And also based on this example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/ when you put a controls in Page Load, it will load in the first load

Comment: would you bother to note delay on other pages with the same master page where there is not code ? 
Try creating a new Web Form with Master Page and observe.